# Manning & Jordan's opinions on the approach to better NLP basing on the article

Tags: nlp, deep-learning

In this [article](http://mitp.nautil.us/article/170/last-words-computational-linguistics-and-deep-learning), Manning discussed about deep learning's impact and contribution to NLP and NLP's future. He quoted Michael Jordan's [AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/2fxi6v/ama_michael_i_jordan/) reply on the R website,

> Although current deep learning research tends to claim to encompass NLP, I'm (1) much less convinced about the strength of the results, compared to the results in, say, vision; (2) much less convinced in the case of NLP than, say, vision, the way to go is to couple huge amounts of data with black-box learning architectures.

and said he agrees with point (1) but feels reserved towards point (2).

The problem is, I am not sure about point (2)'s position.

Later in the article, Manning pointed out that domain knowledge, e.g. linguistics & cognitive psychology, etc., is the center of NLP's recent advancement, and thus, in some sense, downplayed the role of deep learning in advancing NLP.

Therefore, was Manning arguing ***against*** mono-focusing on "huge amounts of data" and "black-box learning architectures" since they are often attributed to deep learning? Was Jordan arguing ***for*** them as the "way to go" for future NLP?

Comment: NVIDIA says, "Deep learning does it all, as long as it's using GPUs"

Comment: Very interesting question but NOT a stackoverflow question.